# Redirecting user when idle in JSF with PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, redirect, primefaces, idle-timer

I would like to send user to `/login.xhtml` if he/she is idle for a given period of time. I have tried PrimeFaces `<p:idlemonitor>` but can't figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: I don't know if you are looking to that in specific way but I can tell you how to do it with JavaScript and jQuery

Comment: Iman Mohamadi you can go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`IdleMonitor`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/) component `<p:idleMonitor>`

```
<p:idleMonitor timeout="3000">
    <p:ajax event="idle" listener="#{idleMonitorBean.processTimeOut()}"/>
</p:idleMonitor>
```

<sub>Note: `timeout` in millseconds</sub>

Then in your listener method just specify the `redirect()` path.

```
@Model
public class IdleMonitorBean {

    public void processTimeOut() throws IOException {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(
                "/contextroot/index.xhtml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can watch for user activities such as clicks (maybe you consider mouse move or scroll as not idle, totally depends on you).

```
    var resetActivityTimer = function () {
        if (typeof window.userActivity != 'undefined')
            clearTimeout(window.userActivity);
        window.userActivity = setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = 'login.xhtml';
        //number of ms until to be considered idle
        }, 30000);
    };

    $(window).click(function () {
        //if user clicked they are not idle
        resetActivityTimer();
    });

    //initialize timer
    resetActivityTimer();
```

Note, If you want to consider scroll or mouse moves as activity don't forget to throttle the events.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to keep things client side in this situation. PrimeFaces Extensions [`pe:javascript`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/clientBehaviours.jsf) can help out here. For example:

```html
<p:idleMonitor timeout="...">
  <pe:javascript event="idle"
                 execute="top.location.href='#{request.contextPath}/login.xhtml'"/>
</p:idleMonitor>
```